# Merge Cell in Excel

Tags: vb.net, merge, cell

How to merge cells using `Cell` and not `Range` in vb.net

I'll try this code but it doesn't work

```
excelSheet.Cells(1, 10).Merge()
```

Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 21):

The cells property of a worksheet refers to a single cell.  So you are trying to merge just the cell at A10.  As its already one cell, this doesn't do anything.  I'm not sure you can do it with just the Cells property, as it will always be one cell only.  Why are you avoiding Range?

This uses range, but would still use the cells property to target the range constraints

```
excelSheet.Range(excelSheet.Cells(1, 1),excelSheet.Cells(1, 10)).Merge
```

Also, I think the command is Merge, not Merge(), at least when I run it.

Sorry if that isn't helpful, give us some more details and I'll look harder if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is the point where you click THE GREEN CHECKMARK ICON AND Give upvotes to contributors.

Comment: @Mark I know this is 9 years old but you may want to consider accepting this question ...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - fix to your values

```
ActiveCell.Value = Range("G8") & Range("H8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It can be used for Range only. I don't know how to merge cells.

```
Dim xlsApp As New Excel.Application
xlsApp .Visible = True
Dim xlsWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("..\TestWorkbook.xls")
Dim xlsWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = DirectCast(xlsWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
xlsWorkSheet.Range("A1:D1").MergeCells = True
```

Remember to import the needed libs.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way

ExcelSheet.Range("A1:H1").merge()